# No module named 'scipy.signal'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Whenever I am trying to import scipy.signal it gives the following error

```
No module named 'scipy.signal'
```

I am currently on python 3.9 and 1.9.3 for scipy.I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling scipy

Comment: Did you name your python script `scipy.py`?

Comment: Are you sure that you've installed `scipy` in the correct interpreter? You might have two (or more) different interpreters installed. You can make doubly-sure that it's really installed by invoking the same command that you use to launch your script and instead of doing `python <my-script-name>.py` you do: `python -m pip list` to list all installed packages on that specific interpreter.

Comment: Try `pip freeze` and see if scipy is in there

Comment: Does `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)` work as expected?

Comment: @JohnGordon no its saved as project.py

Comment: @HampusLarsson scipy is installed in the correct installer

Comment: @Thornily yes scipy is present

Comment: @AskoldIlvento its giving error that module 'scipy' has no attribute '__version__'

Comment: Show us the output of this `import scipy; print(scipy.__file__)`

Comment: There is a definitely problem with `scipy` istelf, not just with `scipy.signal`. You have a kind of mess in your system which make `import scipy` loads not true  `scipy` but something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved the problem by completely uninstalling python and reinstalling it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).